# Is there a way to change input stream from keyboard to arduino in c++

Tags: c++, arduino, istream

While doing a minor project with arduino, I am using Serial to send data to the Arduino IDE.

But when I tried to take an arduino as an input source into other projects using c++ ( similar to keyboard or file input), I could not find any documentation.

Is there a way to read input from an Arduino? If there is, can it be implemented to raspberry pi?

Currently, I am using an Arduino to take data from a sensor (HC-SR04 Ultrasonic sensor) and send integer by integer to a computer where a C++ program receives this value, calculate the distance and display it to the output (monitor) followed by a newline.

EDIT:
Explanation: "can it be implemented to raspberry pi?": I mean, if I want to take input from Pi instead of Arduino (for any distant future project). Apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: In your C++ program you have to read from the serial port. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 7 ,and Code::Blocks IDE for C++ program.

Comment: You are running Windows 7 on a Pi?

Comment: I am using Windows on laptop .

Comment: So you want to write a C++ app on Windows that can read from an Arduino (or maybe later a Pi). You would need to [open the serial port and read data](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q=win32+serial+port+c%2B%2B) sent from the Arduino. You have to come up with a message protocol (or use an existing one) that both the apps understand.